# Is there any twin prime representing function?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, twin-primes

There are many [prime representing functions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_for_primes).

For example, $\lfloor A^{3^n} \rfloor$ is prime representing function because for all positive integers n ,it generates a different prime number. Here $A$ is approximately $1.306377...$ and $\lfloor . \rfloor$ denotes the floor function.

Likewise, is there any function that generates [twin primes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_prime) for all positive integer n?

Comment: Sure: $f(n) = 11$ is a twin prime for all integers $n$.

Comment: Nice joke :) Then I should fix my definition.

Comment: Re your edit: The existence of a function generating *distinct* primes for all positive integers would imply the existence of infinitely many twin primes, which is an unsolved problem for almost 200 years.

Comment: Wow, I never thought of it this way. So this question is useless because if we can find this kind of function, we also prove the conjecture.

Comment: I think that there is some recent result that states that $\liminf (p_{n+1}-p_n)$ is finite, but this is still a bit far from the twin primes' conjecture. Can't remember the author now, maybe he is from Japan? I have not the slightest idea if the proof involves a generating function, though.

Comment: @ajotatxe: Do you mean this (from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_prime#Twin_prime_conjecture)? –  “On 17 April 2013, Yitang Zhang announced a proof that for some integer N that is less than 70 million, there are infinitely many pairs of primes that differ by N.”

Comment: @MartinR Yes, it seems so. And he's from China. But I was thinking about Terence Tao, who is from Australia (though his ethnecity is Chinese, too).

Comment: @MartinR Also, I just realized that your first comment was not joke.

Comment: The best unconditionally proven result is that infinite many prime gaps do not exceed $246$ , but that does not mean that there is a constant such in the case of the primes doing the job.

Comment: See my second-to-latest answer on MSE.  I cover almost exactly what you're asking for including full derivation:  https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4814449/26327

Requirements: modular arithmetic, floor, primorial, sieve-of-Eratosthenes.  This is more of a twin-prime _counting_ formula rather than a spit out some twin primes formula.  But it's a good starting point.   It is actually a generalization of the inclusion-exclusion formula for $\pi(x)$ (usual prime counter) as seen on the prime-counting wikipedia page under algorithms for computing.

Comment: @DanielDonnelly Your approach is correct. After all, this is a combinatorics problem. To deal with this type of problem, techniques from sieve theory are normally used, but despite the advances, the harder is to obtain a proof for a given problem (such as the twin prime conjecture). The issue of definition is the easiest part.